# NodeJS && browser cross compatible websocket client

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, websocket, cross-platform

My goal is to implement a websocket client in JavaScript with specific protocol.

This client should be platform independent. It should be able to run from NodeJS environment and from browsers as well. I know that one option is to use browserify on NodeJS packages and than use the result in browser, but I wonder if there is other more elegant sollution?

Also at the github repo of *ws* NodeJS package that is the most popular I think is being said that it returns global.WebSocket which has slightly different API.
Can I still use it for platform independent client application?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Did you get any good solution for this?

Comment: The project is few years old but I remember that I used browserify to bundle the application and that I had to write a small wrapper that used different API based on the platform.

Comment: Could you share some part of your code? Because I'm facing this problem again, and it looks there are no simple and good solutions yet(very strange).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I used https://websockets.github.io/ws/ package for NodeJS which is compatible with browser WebSocket protocol API.

```
var WebSock = global.WebSocket || global.MozWebSocket || require('ws');

this.sock = new WebSock(url, this.subProtocol);
this.sock.onopen = (evt) => {};
this.sock.onmessage = (msg) => {};
this.sock.onerror = (err) => {};
```

Comment: Important note - it's not fully compatible.

Comment: how?  seems to be the same fwict.   what's missing?

Comment: First of all, the signature of constructor is different. `ws` accepts an object for options, but `WebSocket` only accepts an array of strings for protocols, as shown in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific requirements I have found [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) to work well for both NodeJS (using [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) and browser. It does more then just WebSockets though so make sure and look into it more as it may not suit your specific purposes.

I am using it for a task queue and have been pleased with it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at sockjs for SockJS-client as a JavaScript client library and
SockJS-node for the server implementation.
http://sockjs.org